# Sort in place and O(n) time of an n sized array that takes values of integers from [0..k]

Tags: arrays, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

Is there an algorithm that sorts in place and O(n) time of an n-sized array that takes values of integers from the range [0..k]

Comment: Counting sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort Not in place, additional copy operation required to copy back to source. O(n+k)

Comment: BTW, can be done in place if data contains only numbers (no additional information), in this case original array may be reconstructed completely from histogram.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is! Consider using a [most-significant digit radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Most_significant_digit_radix_sorts), sometimes called *binary quicksort*. This algorithm works in-place, though it requires O(log n) auxiliary space for the recursion stack (I don't know if that's a deal-breaker on your end). The runtime for sorting a list of n numbers whose maximum value is U is O(n log U), and in your case because k is a fixed constant, the runtime is O(n).